# How to define an interface in Typescript for an array of dynamic keys?

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, typescript-types

I have JSON data of this shape:

```
[
   "userId1": {
        "flight_number": "aaa",
        "airport_iata": "AAA"
    },
    "userId2": {
        "flight_number": "bbb",
        "airport_iata": "BBB"
    }
]
```

I am trying to define an interface for this array. The userId keys are dynamic.

```
interface ResourceAllocation {
   flight_number: string
   airport_iata: string
}

interface ResourceAllocationMessage {
   [userId: string]: ResourceAllocation
}
```

However the interface `ResourceAllocationMessage` currently doesn't match the data structure. It would match an **object** with dynamic keys, but I have an **array** of dynamic keys. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can't have an array with keys in JSON; your JSON string is syntactically invalid (have you tried it in any JSON parser? It explodes.) Please [edit] with a [mre] or this will probably be closed as needing debugging details.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz it seems you are correct. The JSON is invalid at the first place. So we can close this.